# How to upload an image to Cloudflare Images from Node using fetch?

Tags: node.js, fetch, cloudflare

I'm trying to upload an image from my computer to Cloudflare Images using Node and the fetch API. They provided me with a curl command that works fine.

```
curl -X POST -F file=@./<file_name> -H "Authorization: Bearer <api_token>" https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/<domain_id>/images/v1
```

When I tried to convert it to fetch, Cloudflare keeps sending me a 400 in their response.

```
const cloudflarePostBody = new FormData();
cloudflarePostBody.append("file", fs.createReadStream("testing.jpeg"));

const cloudflareResponse = await fetch("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/<my_id>/images/v1", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${cloudflareApiToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: cloudflarePostBody,
});
```

My guess is that I'm doing something wrong with how I'm reading the file with `createReadStream`, but a lot of the examples I've looked up showed exactly that. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `fs.readFile()` instead of `fs.createReadStream()`:

```
  fs.readFile("testing.jpeg", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    cloudflarePostBody.append("file", new Blob([data]), "testing.jpeg");
  });
```

Comment: I ended up altering this slightly to be:

`const file = fs.readFileSync(("testing.jpeg"));` and it worked. I also had to remove `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` from the headers, since with the there it was returning a 415 which I found weird, but if it works it works. Thanks for helping me out!